# MySQL - matching and non-matching results in Where IN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find matching and non matching keywords from the database against user entered keywords.

Below is the database schema where we store all the known keywords

```
Table keywords
   keyword varchar
```

Finding matching keywords in simple. We use following query to find matching keywords

```
select keyword from keywords where keyword in ('abc', 'pqr', 'xyz')
```

Where 'abc', 'pqr', 'xyz' are keywords supplied by the user.

However, I also need to find the keywords which are not present in the database. Definitely `NOT IN` does not work as it will return all the tags from the database rather than the one which was not matched. For example, if 'abc' and 'pqr' is present in the database and 'xyz' is not, I am expecting output as following

```
keyword present
abc       1
pqr       1
xyz       0
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - using cte

```
with cte1 as 
(
select 'abc' as key
union 
select 'pqr' union select 'xyz' 
)
select keyword,case when key is null then 0 else 1 end as is_present 
from keywords left join cte1 on keyword=key
```

Comment: There is an error but I got the idea. I am accepting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Select the three keywords and use a subquery to look them up in the keywords table:

```
select
  keyword,
  keyword in (select keyword from keywords) as present
from
(
  select 'abc' as keyword
  union all
  select 'pqr' as keyword
  union all
  select 'xyz' as keyword
) user_keywords
order by keyword;
```