# SQL - How to select Non-matching parameters from WHERE IN clause in query result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two Tables for e.g TabA & TabB, What I want is,

```
SELECT A.PERSONS,
 CASE WHEN A.PERSONS IS NOT NULL THEN 'AVAILABLE' ELSE 'NOT AVAILABLE' END AS PERSON_STATS,
 B.HOBBY
FROM TabA A INNER JOIN TabB B ON A.PersonID = B.PersonID
WHERE A.PERSONS IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNOP', 'QRS', 'TUV', 'WQYZ')
```

I'm getting result from above query is as below -

[image: Result I'm getting]

If person 'ABC', 'DEF' is present in TabA then it will retrieve its record, But I want persons which not matched with Person Name will show is 'Not Available' and vice versa as List provided by user as a Parameter in WHERE clause.

I want result as below -

[image: Result I wanted]

As user list will have n Number of user parameters,
[I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253829/12834383) but is this possible with thousands of recor̥ds in *WHERE IN (Parameters)*.

Please help me to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: This is working please check - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253829/6294821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WITH` Clause for defining temporary table and then apply `LEFT JOIN` to that table.

Here's my solution -

```
    WITH TAB_PERSONS AS
    (
    SELECT 'ABC' AS PERSONS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DEF' AS PERSONS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GHI' AS PERSONS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'JKL' AS PERSONS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'MNOP' AS PERSONS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'QRS' AS PERSONS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'TUV' AS PERSONS FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'WQYZ' AS PERSONS FROM DUAL
    )
    SELECT P.TAB_PERSONS, 
      CASE WHEN A.PERSONS IS NOT NULL THEN 'AVAILABLE' ELSE 'NOT AVAILABLE' END AS PERSON_STATS, 
      B.HOBBY
    FROM TAB_PERSONS P LEFT JOIN TabA A ON A.PERSONS = P.PERSONS
    LEFT JOIN TabB B ON A.PersonID = B.PersonID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` -- after constructing the list of names you want:

```
SELECT p.PERSONS,
       (CASE WHEN A.PERSONS IS NOT NULL THEN 'AVAILABLE' ELSE 'NOT AVAILABLE' END) AS PERSON_STATS,
       B.HOBBY
FROM (SELECT 'ABC' as Persons FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 'DEF' as Persons FROM dual UNION ALL
      . . .
     ) p LEFT JOIN
     TabA A
     ON A.persons = p.persons LEFT JOIN 
     TabB B 
     ON A.PersonID = B.PersonID
```